# How to prevent puppeteer from crawling my website content

Tags: puppeteer

I know that puppeteer is a simple and great tool, which can easily get the website data

As far as I know, if it is headless mode, there will be many properties different from normal browsers

But if I use the following method to link an open browser with the puppeteer , I can't detect it?

First :Modify Desktop Google Browser Shortcut Properties and open brwoser
C:\Users\13632\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222

```
const axios = require('axios')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
async function main() {

    const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version`);
    const webSocketDebuggerUrl = response.data.webSocketDebuggerUrl;

    browser = await puppeteer.connect({
        browserWSEndpoint: webSocketDebuggerUrl,
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--enable-automation"],
        slowMo: 100,
        defaultViewport: { width: 1280, height: 600 },
    });

    
    let target = await browser.waitForTarget(t => t.url().includes("you url"))
    const page = await target.page();

    

}
main()
```

The above method is to link to an opened browser, which is a normal Google browser. It seems that it is impossible to detect whether it is an automated tool? Is there any other way for me to judge whether the other party is a human or a machine

Answer (score 1):

Browser profiling and automation detection (and beating it) is an entire subfield of its own.  Some drivers (chromedriver; I've not used puppeteer) set flags to indicate automated use, but these are easily defeated.  (See for instance `undetected chromedriver` for a package which tries not to be detectable.)

Then there's user profiling (bots tend to click  in predictable ways), running JS in the browser to try to detect the environment, blacklisting ips (most bots are behind proxies), and so on.

Ask yourself: what are you afraid of? And then defend against that.  Anything you put on the Internet can and will be crawled, but you can make it hard to do disruptive things like booking all the concert tickets and the reselling them with a 500% markup.  Specific challenges like that have specific answers; but there is no foolproof way to detect automated browsers, and doing so is a waste of effort.